# Swift Draw polygons/shape in SDK Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, polygon, shapes

I'm developing an application in swift 3.0 with the Google Maps SDK. I have to say this is the first time I work with this SDK and it is so I need a little help. I think what I ask you will be easy for you. What I want to do is when the user enters a map editing mode (like this page http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html ). He can do two things:

- First he could draw polygons on the map (to mark the boundaries of a farmer field). I want the user to press a point on the map and generate a line until the next point. In this way, he will generate lines until the polygon is closed.
  My code for drawing polygon attach below. But the problem is that it never closes the polygon.But the problem is that **I want it when the beginning of the line and the end are touched or the lines cross, close the polygon**.How do I do it? As you see in the picture, I can draw infinite lines.

  ```
  let pathEditField = GMSMutablePath()
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

      if modeEditing {
          pathEditField.add(coordinate)
          let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: pathEditField)
          polyline.map = mapView

      }
  }
  ```
- **Second, once the polygon is drawn, the vertices are highlighted in some way, then you can move that vertex to finish adjusting.**

I leave you a screenshot, so that you get an idea where the user can create the polygon and where to adjust the vertices.

**The problem is that I do not know how to do it besides I can not find documentation for it. My question is, do you know any tutorial where something similar is done? Or can you start the code a bit without writing it?**

[image]

The user can determine the limits of his land parcel by creating a polygon and adjusting it afterwards.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to create polygon [GoogleMaps documentaion](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/)

```
 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 76.0,
                                          longitude: 87.0,
                                          zoom: 18)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)

    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    //Add vertex's to Path like as shown bellow
    //get vertices from map
   // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes

let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))

    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeColor = .blue
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
    polyline.map = mapView
```

Comment: Thanks @Phani Sai !  Currently the code that I am using is as you say, but I want it when the beginning of the line and the end are touched or the lines cross, close the polygon :( . But I can't detect this case :( .. Any idea?

Comment: add starting location point in the ending so u can close the polygon.

Comment: Thanks @Phani Sai !!  its a good idea! You tell me to keep my starting position. But what I want to do is, when the last point is near the beginning, close the polygon. How I do this automatically ?

Comment: Hi @PhaniSai , How to get GMSMutablePath cordinates ? Did you add manually ? I need dynamic based on my current location , can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 5 you can use bellow like.**
Your image look like bellow
[image]

1. Add pod to your project

   pod 'GoogleMaps'
     pod 'GooglePlaces'
2. Add  api key from google in AppDelegate like bellow

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     GMSServices.provideAPIKey("Your api key")
     GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("your api key")

    return true
   }
   ```
3. Add GMSMapView to your view & connect to viewController
4. Paste the bellow code to your viewCotroller

   import UIKit

   ```
   import GoogleMaps

   import GooglePlaces

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!    

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.4, longitude:-122.0, zoom: 10)
   let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
   mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
   //mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
   mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true;
   self.view = mapView

   // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
   let marker = GMSMarker()
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0)
   marker.title = "Bangladesh"
   //marker.snippet = "Malaysia"
   marker.map = mapView

   // Create a rectangular path
   let rect = GMSMutablePath()
   rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
   rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
   rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
   rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))

   // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
   let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
   polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
   polygon.strokeColor = UIColor.init(hue: 210, saturation: 88, brightness: 84, alpha: 1)
   //polygon.strokeColor = .black
   polygon.strokeWidth = 2
   polygon.map = mapView

     }

    }
   ```

   You can download full source from GitHub: GitHub Link: https://github.com/enamul95/GoogleMapPolyLine

Comment: Hi @Enamul Haque , How to get GMSMutablePath cordinates ? Did you add manually ?
I need dynamic based on my current location , can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps sdk for iOS provides a class named

> GMSPolygon

which provides the functionality you are searching for.

Just provide the initializer with a

> GMSMutablePath

that contains the coordinates for the polygon.

```
let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
polygon.strokeColor = .red
polygon.fillColor = .blue
polygon.strokeWidth = 1.0
polygon.map = mapView
```