# How to draw a polygon from a json file?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, polygon, geojson

I am trying to draw a polygon on google map from a geo json file. i know how can i draw path from few coordinate but i am unable to draw this from google map

Here is my JSON file

```
 {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        [
            90.35087585449219,
            23.87767555995429
        ],
        [
            90.35293579101562,
            23.877832529038052
        ],

        [
            90.45867919921875,
            23.662449542924175
        ],
        [
            90.45455932617188,
            23.66103447347277
        ],
        [
            90.35053253173828,
            23.872966398925893
        ],
        [
            90.35018920898438,
            23.87516402872517
        ],
        [
            90.35087585449219,
            23.87767555995429
        ]
    ]
]
}
```

How can i draw polygon form this json ?
i want it dynamic way not static way also for google map

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Draw polygons/shape in SDK Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061084/swift-draw-polygons-shape-in-sdk-google-maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way it may help :)

```
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var coordinates: [coordinates]
    var type : String
}
struct coordinates : Decodable {
    var lng: String
    var lat: String
}
```

Create 2 struct

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document", withExtension: "json") {

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)

            for te in jsonData.coordinates {
                path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: te.lat.toDouble(), longitude: te.lng.toDouble()))
            }
        }
        catch {
            //Handle error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    rectangle.strokeColor = .red
    rectangle.strokeWidth = 5.0
    rectangle.map = mapView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you parse and create CLLLocation2D array, and add all coordinates in this array;

```
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: yourArray, count: yourArray.count)
yourMapView.addOverlay(polygon)
```

Please check before you create, first element of coordinates should be same the last element of your coordinates..

By the way I assumed that you already extend your view controller and add below method. If you didn't extend, please write down an extension and delegate self.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {


    let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.lineWidth = 5 //Customize as you wish
    renderer.fillColor = .green
    renderer.strokeColor = .red
    return renderer 
}
```

Comment: You are rendering for map-kit. but i want for google map